# when a capacitors is being charging from a battery is battery discharging?

Tags: capacitor, basic

I'm studying yet.

Is a battery discharging when capacitor connected to it is charging?

Please explain how does it work!

Comment: Please provide a schematic of the circuit you are referring to. What you are asking is unclear. How are the battery and the capacitor connected to each other? Just the capacitor in parallel with the battery? Or what else?

Comment: Normally a capacitor is connectrd to normal battery....i want to know whetrher  battery will be discharged  as capacitor has been charged .....

Answer (score 1):

The act of taking current from the battery to charge the capacitor does discharge the battery.  However, for reasonable sizes of battery and capacitor, this will result in a very small depletion of charge in the battery.

Comment: @charlie What Peter says. As a guide a 1000 uF capacitor charged to 1.5V stores about 1.1 J (1.1 Watt seconds) of energy. An AA Alkaline battery stores about 4000 Joule of energy. So the capacitor contains about 0.03% of the energy in the battery. OR it would take about 3600 1000 uF capacitors charged to 1.5V to equal the energy in the battery. SO yes, the battery dischaarges when it charges the capacitor, but not by much. (For technical reasons - just connecting the battery to the capacitor to charge it will waste about 1/2 the energy in the process. There are ways of avoiding this.